# Price Comparison MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm trying to do a price comparison between a ecommerce site we run and a competitor.

We have all their prices in 1 table, and we would like to display our products next to the prices for our store and the competitors for future marketing efforts.

There is around 109,000 products we are trying to do this for and the query I have so far is this:

```
SELECT 
    hoge_thehog_magento.`catalog_product_flat_1`.`name`,
hoge_oem.`crossref`.`oursku`,
hoge_thehog_magento.`catalog_product_flat_1`.`price`,
hoge_oem.`crossref`.`jhdprice`   
FROM
hoge_oem.`crossref`
    INNER JOIN
hoge_thehog_magento.`catalog_product_flat_1` ON hoge_thehog_magento.`catalog_product_flat_1`.sku = hoge_oem.`crossref`.`oursku`;
```

the problem is, it keeps timing out. In mysql workbench no errors come up, it will just run and run then give error code 2013.

Is there a better way to write this query? I am struggling here :(

Comment: limit data retrieval by dates,products,region any thing concerned to you

Comment: It's going to join all of your products to themselves as well as all competitors to themselves if oursku and sku are set for all rows without distinguishing which are yours

Comment: Also check that you have indexes on sku y oursku fields.

Comment: make sure there is an index on both `catalog_product_flat_1.sku` and `crossref.oursku`

Comment: Extra information; the timeout and the error code 2013 are probably the same error ;)